# Add columns with dummies and specific headers to dataset

Tags: dataset, column

I got a dataset that looks like the following example:

```
`exampleData = Dataset[{<|"CompanyName" -> "ca", "period" -> 2015, 
"return" -> 0.3456, "ROE" -> 0.3926|>, <|"CompanyName" -> "ca", 
"period" -> 2014, "return" -> 0.2236, "ROE" -> 0.08894|>, <|
"CompanyName" -> "cb", "period" -> 2014, "return" -> 0.0247, 
"ROE" -> 0.1583|>, <|"CompanyName" -> "cb", "period" -> 2015, 
"return" -> 0.01757, "ROE" -> 0.0662|>, <|"CompanyName" -> "cc", 
"period" -> 2015, "return" -> 0.2145, "ROE" -> 0.1171|>, <|
"CompanyName" -> "cc", "period" -> 2014, "return" -> 0.08972, 
"ROE" -> 0.5339|>}]`
```

What I am trying to do, is applying a function to the dataset that creates as many new columns as their are different values in `CompanyName` and at the same time fills it with the according dummies, in a way that the result looks like this:

```
exampleResult = Dataset[{<|"CompanyName" -> "ca", "period" -> 2015, 
"return" -> 0.3456, "ROE" -> 0.3926, "dummyCA" -> 1, 
"dummyCB" -> 0, "dummyCC" -> 0|>, <|"CompanyName" -> "ca", 
"period" -> 2014, "return" -> 0.2236, "ROE" -> 0.08894, 
"dummyCA" -> 1, "dummyCB" -> 0, "dummyCC" -> 0|>, <|
"CompanyName" -> "cb", "period" -> 2014, "return" -> 0.0247, 
"ROE" -> 0.1583, "dummyCA" -> 0, "dummyCB" -> 1, 
"dummyCC" -> 0|>, <|"CompanyName" -> "cb", "period" -> 2015, 
"return" -> 0.01757, "ROE" -> 0.0662, "dummyCA" -> 0, 
"dummyCB" -> 1, "dummyCC" -> 0|>, <|"CompanyName" -> "cc", 
"period" -> 2015, "return" -> 0.2145, "ROE" -> 0.1171, 
"dummyCA" -> 0, "dummyCB" -> 0, "dummyCC" -> 1|>, <|
"CompanyName" -> "cc", "period" -> 2014, "return" -> 0.08972, 
"ROE" -> 0.5339, "dummyCA" -> 0, "dummyCB" -> 0, 
"dummyCC" -> 1|>}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way, but the following does the job:

```
comps = exampleData[Union, "CompanyName"];
dummies = "dummy" <> ToUpperCase[#] & /@ comps;
funcs = Function[{x, y}, x -> (If[# == y, 1, 0] &)] @@@ Thread[Normal /@ {dummies, comps}];
ds2 = exampleData[All, Key["CompanyName"] /*Association[funcs]];
Dataset[Join @@@ Thread[Normal /@ {exampleData, ds2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively you can use `Boole` instead of `If` to define `funcs`:

```
 funcs= Function[{x, y}, x -> (Boole[# == y] &)] @@@ Thread[Normal /@ {dummies, comps}];
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you!

Comment: @Murr, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `JoinAcross`

```
data = Normal @ exampleResult;

a = Union @ data[[All, 1]];
b = Table["CompanyName", Length @ a];
c = "dummy" <> ToUpperCase[#] & /@ a;

join = Replace[Transpose[{b, a, c}], {b_, a_, c_} :> <|b -> a, c -> 1|>, {1}]

JoinAcross[data, join, "CompanyName"] /. Missing[_] :> 0 // Dataset
```

[image]